# Windows 10 IoT - Raspberry pi 2

Tags: iot, ip-camera, windows-10-iot-core

I have to build a rover which has a camera on it and through webcam samples i am able to view the preview of it. I also came up with another app with has controls for the rover's motors. It works fine when i connect this device to a monitor and work with it, but for my purpose it needs to be headless. Is there any way i could remotely access the application. I am stuck up with so many different solutions like duplicating the entire project as webpage or could open the same application is the development machine that they communicate with each other. All i have to do is remotely control the rover with a video preview and even lower fps is acceptable.

Comment: Questions like: "Which is the best tool for some task?" tend to be more based on opinion than on hard facts. On SO such questions are not very appreciated. Try to be more specifc, like: "I tried it with this set of tools. The technical difficulty I see here is ..... . How do I solve this problem using .... ?

Comment: Any solution is fine. I tried them but it wasn't successful. Please help me with this.

Comment: Please rephrase your question

Comment: What do you mean with "headless"?

Comment: Possible dublicate: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/23416/remote-desktop-for-windows-10-iot

Comment: @BerndGit that is not a duplicate question. My purpose is to be able to control an application in iot device remotely through internet.

Comment: Your are looking for a tool which: `- runs on Windows 10 IoT (ARM), particularly for Raspberry Pi 2 (server side), - forwards the screen to a Windows 10 (x86, Desktop) client, and  frame rate should be at least 5 per second` Correct?  Additional requirement of you is to forward mouse and Keyboard to the Pi 2.

Comment: @BerndGit yes that's exactly what I am looking for.

Comment: @Vignesh: Yes and this is exactly part of the wording at: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/23416/remote-desktop-for-windows-10-iot   Therefore I suspected a dublicate. Seems that remote desktop is no solution.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways to do this. (As @BerndGit implies.)

The easiest (IMHO) is to SSH in to the RPi from another computer and forward X11. That second computer will need to be configured for accepting X11 sessions.

Look for "SSH X11 Display Forwarding" for details on how to make this work on your setup.

Comment: Am sorry but the title clearly says am using win 10 iot.

Comment: Am sorry, but you misunderstand. From your question it sounds like you're running Win 10 IOT on the Pi. You need a second computer (with a head to see the preview video sent from the pi). This second computer will need to be configured in addition to the Win 10 IOT. You did not mention what that second computer was.

Comment: Thanks, I need to access the iot device from the second machine which is used for the development of application.